# Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in

Tags: php

I keep getting this error message whenever I click through to the blog page. It was working fine until I began building the forgotten password functionality for the site.

Does anyone know what this means in general and what I might have to do to get stop the error? I've googled this and gotten nowhere so apologies if this is seen as a broad question.

Full error message: **Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\weinspire\blog\app\controllers\users.php on line 95**

There's three more error message underneath this referring to lines 96, 97 and 98 too.

```html
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $user = selectOne($table, ['id' => $_GET['id']]);

    $id = $user['id'];
    $username = $user['username'];
    $admin = $user['admin'];
    $email = $user['email'];
}
```

The error message comes up four times and refers to each line with a variable in.

```html
<?php

include("path.php");
include_once(ROOT_PATH . '/app/controllers/posts.php');
// include(ROOT_PATH . '/app/controllers/users.php');

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $post = selectOne('posts', ['id' => $_GET['id']]);
}
$topics = selectAll('topicstable');
$posts = selectAll('posts', ['published' => 1]);

?>
```

Comment: Hi. Can you provide full error message? It should also say in which file it happened. Then try to analyze that code or add it to your question. We can't help you much without detailed info.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I've added the code it refers to and the full error message @DesertFox

Comment: Thank you. Which one in your code is line #95?

Comment: $id = $user['id']; 
There are four error messages altogether, one for each of the three subsequent lines too

Comment: Can you show output of `var_dump($user);`? (insert this line just before `$id = $user['id'];`)

Comment: The output I'm getting is NULL

Comment: This means it can't get the user via ID in some circumstances. This makes `$user` NULL instead of array with user-related data. So you need add a check if `$user` is set. If it is, you can then get your values from the array.

Comment: How do you mean check if the user is set?

Comment: It means `if (isset($user)) { }`. Then you'll have to check _why_ `selectOne ()` returns NULL..

Comment: I have done this check and for some reason, only on blog pages the $user variable isn't set. @RobertoCaboni On every other page it is fine

Comment: Without seeing all of the code it might be difficult to trace but 2 things you could check: is $table variable still pointing to the users table, and, is the blog passing in its own id get parameter? In situations like this I use XDebug so I can set a breakpoint in the code and inspect the state of the variables. Perhaps you can install it in xampp? I don't use xampp so can't help with that I'm afraid.

Comment: Hi @Mark, yes the blog is passing through its own id get parameter (I've updated the question to show you the code), I'm not sure how I'd go about rectifying this, and I'm slightly confused as it's been like this for a while now and all of a sudden I'm getting errors. $table variable pointing in right direction though. Thanks for your help

Comment: That would be it then. You'd need to change the blog get request to use a different name, e.g. blog_id. It could have been working all this time because only now you have more blogs than users? e.g. say you had 15 users with ids 1-15 and 15 blog posts with ids 1-15 then all that time it would work (although looking up the wrong user using the blog ID and not the user ID). Now say you get 1 more blog post with ID 16. Now suddenly there is no user with ID 16 so now it fails. This is all assumption mind you but hopefully could help.

Comment: That hasn't worked either, changed all requests and the database column to blog_id and still getting the same error message, I'm stumped

Comment: Almost sorted it I think @Mark, it was a bit messy but you were right though haha, I got confused at first - just took me a bit of time to get my head around, cheers for your help!